# How to combine more than 1 dimension into single dimension SSAS

Tags: ssas

I have a fact table having foreign key relationship with other 4 tables. Now, I have four dimensions and 1 measure. I need to combine all 4 dimensions into 1. Anyone suggest me how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to combine them? Are you saying when building a report you need to report by a combination of store and product (for example)? Or are you suggesting you want to put stores and products in the same dimension?

Comment: Yes. In my case I have a Item count as Measures/Fact table item and Items Locations, Items Status, Items Collections, Items Branch as 4 different dimensions. So, I need to combine all 4 dimensions into 1 as Items Properties.

Comment: sorry to be hardheaded. Why do you need to combine them?

Comment: It is the requirement from my client. May be to group same properties into single dimension so that the end user can easily navigate through different attributes instead of dimensions.

Comment: how many rows in the fact table? Are you using SSAS Multidimensional of Tabular or undecided?

Comment: 3 or 4 lacs of rows in my fact table. I am using Multidimensional approach.

Comment: uh... Not familiar with lacs. Can you clarify?

Comment: 3,00,000 to 5,00,000 records

Comment: I assume 5,00,000 is the same thing as 500,000 and is not 5 million (not 5,000,000)? I'm not so concerned if you have less than a million rows assuming decent hardware. I am more concerned with dimensions that are millions of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished with a project optimizing processing time. They had a dimension that used the fact key as the dimension key. The fact and dimension each had 300 million rows. The hardware was good and it took 3 hours to process the dimension and another hour to process the fact partitions. Dimensions can't be partitioned in Multidimensional.

We took apart that 300 million row dimension and build separate dimensions logically by entity. Now processing is about an hour for everything.

All that is to say that you can create a dimension with the same number of rows as your fact table but processing performance will suffer. I would only combine unrelated dimensions of held down and tortured by the business. Let business users dictate the business need not the implementation details.

That being said with under a million rows you will probably be five either way. Your question was how to combine them. One way is to use all 4 dimension key columns in the key of your dimension. Your combined dimension would have one key and the KeyColumns property would mention all 4 key columns from your fact table. Then add the dimension attribute columns from all 4 dimension tables to that one SSAS dimension. Due to the relationship on the DSV this is allowed.

Alternately if your fact table has an identity column you can use that as the key.